# I cannot compile an Android app with Qt

Tags: android, qt, compiler-errors, android-ndk, mips

I'm so confused. I cannot compile an apk app. This is what I've done:

Installed Qt with this image (I know it's rather old, I will update
    it soon):

> qt-windows-opensource-5.1.1-android-x86-win32-offline.exe

Downloaded Android SDK and NDK and added in Options > Android

Now there is a weird warning and no apk output:

> Qt versions for architectures mips, arm, x86 are missing. To add the
>   Qt versions, select Options > Build & Run >Qt versions.

[image: Qt versions for architectures mips, arm, x86 are missing. To add the Qt versions, select Options > Build & Run >Qt versions.]

And this is the Build & Run page:

[image: Build & Run page, Qt]

***Update:***

I followed these steps and the build process finished. But some errors appeared :

> http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-mobile-app-tutorial.html

```
10:47:21: Running steps for project Quick_test...
10:47:21: Configuration unchanged, skipping qmake step.
10:47:21: Starting: "C:\Qt\Qt5.3.0\Tools\mingw482_32\bin\mingw32-make.exe" 
mingw32-make: Nothing to be done for 'first'.
10:47:24: The process "C:\Qt\Qt5.3.0\Tools\mingw482_32\bin\mingw32-make.exe" exited normally.
10:47:24: Starting: "C:\Qt\Qt5.3.0\Tools\mingw482_32\bin\mingw32-make.exe" INSTALL_ROOT="C:\Users\rosta\Documents\Qt Projects\build-Quick_test-Android_for_armeabi_v7a_GCC_4_9_Qt_5_3_0-Release\android-build" install
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
Makefile:773: recipe for target 'install_target' failed
mingw32-make: *** [install_target] Error 1
10:47:27: The process "C:\Qt\Qt5.3.0\Tools\mingw482_32\bin\mingw32-make.exe" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project Quick_test (kit: Android for armeabi-v7a (GCC 4.9, Qt 5.3.0))
When executing step 'Copy application data'
10:47:27: Elapsed time: ۰:۰۰:۰۶.
```

Comment: You have to specify the JDK path and Ant path in that first dialog. Just follow the directions here: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/androidgs.html

Comment: I did all except installing Apache Ant. Is this java library for java programming? I'm using C++. And what's wrong with "Build & Run" ?

Comment: Qt/Android uses Java and JNI internally to interface with android, and also for packaging/deployment. There's probably nothing wrong with Build & run, it detects armv7, the other architectures are probably just not shipped in your (ancient) Qt installer?

Comment: That's the problem. I configured Ant and JDK and the problem resolved :)